# RecyclerView + GridView + Single ImageView = align to center of screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView + GridView with a single ImageView. Right now I am using Grid of 3 and there is problem: The images aren't center aligned.

Image:

[image]

This is the xml for the RecyclerView:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="601dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the xml for the single image view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip" >    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="118dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your imageview have android:layout_marginStart="42dp" but doesn't have a android:layout_marginEnd="42dp".

Comment: Thank you! Do you suggest me to maybe switch the Relative layout parent of the ImageView to Constraint? Do I even need to specify parent layout for a single recycler item?

Comment: If its just a single view inside your viewholder, you don't need a viewgroup as a parent. 
Another advice: maybe 42dp at start and end would be too much. Try decrease your margins to better fit at screen of any size/density.